# .Net Web Api (multipart-formdata) values are being received as null from angular

Tags: .net, angular, .net-core, file-upload

when i try to post my request through angular form my SampleDTO's Name feild and File feild comes null

My .net core api

```
    [HttpPost("file")]
    public ActionResult<string> Upload([FromForm]SampleDTO dto)
    {
        try
        {

            var folderName = Path.Combine("wwwroot", "Images/products");
            var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);
            if (dto.File != null && dto.File?.Length > 0)
            {
                var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(dto.File.ContentDisposition)
                .FileName.Trim('"');
                var fullPath = Path.Combine(pathToSave, fileName);
                var dbPath = Path.Combine(folderName, fileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    dto.File.CopyTo(stream);
                    return Ok(dto.File.FileName+" ");
                }
            }
            return BadRequest();
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

My DTO

```
public class SampleDTO
 {
   [Required]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public IFormFile File { get; set; }
 }
```

```
export interface ISample
{
    name:string;
    file:File;
}
```

My Angular Service Method

```
createSample(data:any)
  {
    return this.http.post("https://localhost:7169/api/product/file",data);
  }
```

My Angular Component OnSubmit() Method

```
onSubmit(data:any)
  {
    console.log(data as ISample);

    this.productService.createSample(data as ISample).subscribe(res=>console.log(res));
  }
```

My Angular Component OnChange Method here I assign the file

```
onChange(event:any)
  {
    this.file = event.target.files[0] as File;
    this.testForm.patchValue(
      {
        file:this.file
      }); 
  }
```

My HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="this.testForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" formControlName="name">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" (change)="onChange($event)">
    <button (click)="this.onSubmit(this.testForm.value)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My Problem is when it's coming from angular api SampleDTO's feilds Name and File are null
Screen Shot
[Screen Shot of the debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz9Er.png)

Comment: To submit a request body with file, we need to specify the content-type as "multipart/form-data". Thus the content-type with "application/json" is incorrect. By the way, you don't need to specify the `headers` parameter. Angular HttpClient will handle the request with specifying its content-type.

Comment: @YongShun  I have modified the code but still getting the same result

Comment: Check the browser DevTools, network tab, does the request sent contain the body with data and in content-type: multipart/form-data?

Comment: @YongShun in network tab there is no header is application/json

Comment: @YongShun when i tried the same request via Postman it's coming up with data as expected but when i tried it with angular it's coming null

Comment: @YongShun I sloved the above problem thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Changed My component code, I've created `formData` object and assign **name** and **file** to that `formData`. Then I've passed that `formData` object to my service method.

```
onSubmit(data:any)
  {
    console.log(data as ISample);
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name",data.name)
    formData.append("file",this.file);
    this.productService.createSample(formData).subscribe(res=>console.log(res));
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).